# extra characters after close-brace

Tags: linux, tcl, freebsd

The same code that works on Linux doesn't work on FreeBSD

**On Linux**

```
% set timeZone "-4:0"
-4:0
% set timeZone [format "%+03d%02d" {*}[scan $timeZone "%d:%d"]]
-0400
% puts $tcl_version
8.5
```

**On FreeBSD**

```
% set timeZone "-4:0"
-4:0
% set timeZone [format "%+03d%02d" {*}[scan $timeZone "%d:%d"]]
extra characters after close-brace
% puts $tcl_version
8.4
```

How to make this work on both FreeBSD and Linux?

Comment: It looks like your installation of FreeBSD is using a version of Tcl that is no longer supported. Can you just update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `eval`, since list expansion (`{*}`) [was implemented in Tcl 8.5](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158). You could perhaps use something like this:

```
set timeZone "-4:0"
set code "format \"%+03d%02d\" [scan $timeZone "%d:%d"]"
# This gives you "format "%+03d%02d" -4 0"
set timeZone [eval $code]
```

If you don't like escaping the quotes, you can use braces (which IMO is a bit cleaner):

```
set code "format {%+03d%02d} [scan $timeZone {%d:%d}]"
```

---

Or the more elaborate 8.4 solution from the wiki can be found [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17379).